# Does TI or someone provide the component libraries for free for KiCad?

Tags: pcb, components, design, kicad, library

I am designing a circuit and PCB using KiCad. I would like to know whether TI or someone provides component libraries for free for Kicad or not.

Comment: e.g, ADS1256. I can't find ADS1256 in any default libraries of KiCAD

Comment: Bill, does the device have a standard footprint to be found in KiCAD?

Comment: I strongly advise to use the footprints defined by the IPC-7351 standard. IIRC the footprint wizzard tries to stick to it. Alternatively, check https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/503740/kicad-footprint-or-supplier-footprint for some predefined footprint libaries. But not sure if they can be still imported.

Answer (score 6):

The normal thing to do is to make the components yourself using the [symbol editor and the footprint editor.](https://docs.kicad.org/6.0/en/getting_started_in_kicad/getting_started_in_kicad.html#tutorial_part_4_custom_symbols_and_footprints)

You'll have to get the datasheet of the component and use the given measurements to draw the footprint.  You'll have to draw the schematic symbol yourself, as well.  You'll often find that there's a similar component that you can copy and modify.  For your ADS1256, you might look and see if KiCad has a multichannel ADC that you could copy.

---

There are sites like [SnapEDA](https://www.snapeda.com/kicad/) that have components for KiCad.  You have at least a starting point, but you'll have to double check the downloaded component (compare everything to the datasheet) to be sure it is correct.

I've gone over to just drawing my own components for my personal projects.  There may be mistakes in them, but then at least they are **my** mistakes that I have to correct.

Answer (score 5):

The first two coming to mind:
https://www.ultralibrarian.com/
https://www.snapeda.com/
Then I'm sure there are others as well. Always double-check packages and pins, sometimes I've got trouble with a *nearly exact* package (...)